# Not showing any output

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I am facing a problem while coding Linked List implementation in c++. Whenever I am trying to add an element he following code doesn't show any output. What's wrong with the code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* ptr;

    Node(int val) {
        data = val;
        ptr = NULL;
    }
};

void addItem(struct Node* head, int val) {
   struct Node* n = new Node(val);
    if(head == NULL){
        head = n;
        return;
    }
    
        struct Node* cur = head;     
        while(cur->ptr != NULL){  
            cur = cur->ptr;
        }
        cur->ptr = n;
    
}

void printList(struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* cur = head;
    while(cur != NULL) {
        cout << cur->data << " ";
        cur = cur->ptr;
    }
}

int main() {

    struct Node* head = NULL;
    
    addItem(head, 1);
    addItem(head, 2);
    addItem(head, 3);
    addItem(head, 4);
    printList(head);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program it shows nothing on the terminal.

Output:

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Sonu\" && g++ LinkedList.cpp -o LinkedList && "c:\Users\Sonu\"LinkedList

[Done] exited with code=0 in 3.436 seconds
```

Comment: Remember that arguments in C++ are by default pass *by value*, which means the value used in the call is *copied* into the argument variable. That means when you modify the argument variable (like the assignment to `head` in your `addItem` function) you only modify the local variable and not the original variable used in the call.

Comment: So, what can I do now? can you give me the solution?

Comment: A function can modify a thing if you pass it a pointer *to that thing*. This is true even if the thing itself is a pointer. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: Pass by *reference* instead?

Comment: `struct Node* n = new Node(val);` -- There is no need to specify `struct` here, and in other places in your code.  Just `Node* n = new Node(val);` is sufficient.  C++ is not C.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `head` by double pointer or by reference. Otherwise it will be just a copy on function argument which will get destroyed when coming out of the function.

```
void addItem(Node** head, int val) {
    Node* n = new Node(val);
    if(*head == NULL){
        *head = n;
        return;
    }
    
    Node* cur = *head;     
    while(cur->ptr != NULL){  
        cur = cur->ptr;
    }
    cur->ptr = n;        
}

// ...

addItem(&head, 1); // take the address with &
```

or

```
void addItem(Node*& head, int val) {
    Node* n = new Node(val);
    if(head == NULL){
        head = n;
        return;
    }
    
    Node* cur = head;     
    while(cur->ptr != NULL){  
        cur = cur->ptr;
    }
    cur->ptr = n;        
}

// ...

addItem(head, 1); // no change needed
```